# No such file or directory error in linux

Tags: linux, directory

Recently I have installed a program called "paradigm". In the program path (/home/hora/Paradigm/) there is a directory "testdata" (/home/hora/Paradigm/testdata) which includes a shell script that runs an example test of the application.The first time I installed the program I was able to run the shell script(runtests.sh) but now that I try to run it I get the error of " No such file or directory", although the files which is mentioned by the error are there. I am sure the problem is due to lack of my knowledge to linux and your help will be appreciated. To show the situation:

```
hora@serv:~/Paradigm/testdata$ ./runtests.sh 
Testing node splitting [1/2], should take seconds
diff: needs_split_1.out: No such file or directory
./runtests.sh: line 6: ../pathwaytab2daifg: No such file or directory
```

But if I list the content of directory the mentioned files are there:

```
hora@serv:~/Paradigm/testdata$ ls 
complex_family_pathway.tab      needs_split_1.cfg          needs_split_2.out          runtests.sh                    small_disconnected_pathway.tab
complex_family_pathway.tab.out  needs_split_1.out          needs_split_2.pathway.tab
```

And then:

```
 hora@serv:~/Paradigm$ ls 
 common.h           configuration.o    
 evidencesource.o  helperScripts  makefile         
 pathwaytab2daifg.cpp  pathwaytab.h      test1 configuration.cpp 
 evidencesource.cpp  externVars.cpp    main.cpp       paradigm         
 pathwaytab2daifg.o    pathwaytab.o      testdata configuration.h   
 evidencesource.h    externVars.o      main.o         pathwaytab2daifg 
 pathwaytab.cpp        README.mediawiki
```

This is the script content(the problematic part):

```
#!/bin/bash

set -o pipefail
cd 
echo Testing node splitting [1/2], should take seconds
../pathwaytab2daifg needs_split_1.pathway.tab needs_split_1.cfg  \
    | diff needs_split_1.out - || exit 1
```

Comment: Your error message is complaining about `../pathwaytab2daifg`, which is a **relative** path. Are you changing the current directory in your script before this point? If so, either change back before executing this line, or change it to an absolute path.

Comment: The "pathwaytab2daifg" is exactly one level up than where I try to run the script I mean in the right place and I have not changed any thing. Everything is in their place but I get this error.

Comment: @Jost I added the script

Comment: remove the `cd`, which brings you back to your home directory, and you will be fine. (hopefully) ;-)

Comment: @Jost yes you are right now it is running, I mean after removing "cd". Actually I am not an expert in linux but I know what "cd" does :)). The question is why it was running last week, I mean the same script but it is not running now. Had I run the script in another path rather than where I mention above?

Comment: @hora In detail `cd` brings you back to the directory stored in your current environment variable `$HOME` - may be this environment variable was different OR was set in another part of the script.

Comment: @Jost there is no command in the script which changes the directory path. So I should conclude that my $HOME has been set to where the executing files(paradigm and pathwattab2daifg) were installed. Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the authors of this script want you to set `HOME` to `~/Paradigm`, or they expect you to install directly in your HOME directory (`~`) rather than in `~/Paradigm`.  Either way, this is an error on their part.  A simple fix may be to move the installation to `~`, or try:

`env HOME=$(pwd) ./runtests.sh`

(Note that the `env` is not necessary unless you are running a `csh` family shell such as `csh` or `tcsh`).  Setting `HOME` changes the behavior of `cd` when called with no arguments and makes the value of HOME the target directory.

Comment: Actually the installation was so tricky that I prefer not to do it once more. But thanks a lot your second solution works perfectly. I mean all the suggestions here worked well but I still does not understand why did not receive this error previous time.

Answer (score 3):

This line:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -o pipefail

cd #<----- here!

echo Testing node splitting [1/2], should take seconds
../pathwaytab2daifg needs_split_1.pathway.tab needs_split_1.cfg  \
    | diff needs_split_1.out - || exit 1
```

is changing the directory to `~/`, which is the default argument of `cd` if you don't pass a path to it (see [here](http://linuxcommand.org/lc3_man_pages/cdh.html)).

You could fix the script to work from anywhere if you like, by giving `cd` an absolute path i.e. changing that `cd` line to `cd /home/hora/Paradigm/testdata`.

Comment: Many thanks. But regarding your suggestion to change back to where I was before, I tried every path but it did not work and I have not changed anything in the script. I really liked to learn where does this problem come from.

Comment: @hora Sorry, see my edit. I also meant change the script, not change dir in your shell. :)

Answer (score -1):

I know this is a VERY old question BUT I think my answer is relevant for others that did not find their answer.

I've been using Linux on a home server since about 2000. Recently, I've upgraded a home server to 64-bit architecture (DELL R510 w/ 2 @ Xeon).

I've been using a program (text2pdf.c) since my 32-bit kernel 2.4.32 days. I had forgotten to clean and re-make the executable file before installing it on the 64-bit system. Hence, I received the same error BUT not for the reasons stated in all the answers I've found online. 'which' and 'type' gave no clues BUT using 'file' gave me the info on the libraries that were linked at compile time and they were 2.4.32 libraries. Obviously, OLD 32-bit libraries on a 4.x 64-bit kernel didn't fly. Make clean, make (and make install) cleared the problem.

Peace and blessings,
JQ